# Do I need an extra deep old-work box for a stucco wall?

Tags: wiring

Do I need a deep rework box to fit to the 1 inch wall thickness. Do they manufacture one that the  tabs are back about 1-2 inches? How does one get the tabs in the hole to secure them tight?

Answer (score 1):

#### Old Work Box Mounting Accessories [Link](http://www.garvinindustries.com/electrical-junction-boxes/box-accessories/box-mounting)

1. Option One: Old-work Switch Box Supports with 2-1/2” Long Legs - Most common technique, though probably not as easy as option 2, which is relatively a new design.
2. Option Two: Cut In Box "Old Work" Mounting Clips.

These items should never be used to support a fixture.  Strictly speaking, only switches and outlets on a vertical wall, or similar.

I would opt for 2, as it may be easier for those not familiar with item 1 and thick walls.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are metal boxes such as [these](http://www.lowes.com/pd_74219-53911-CDOWTG-16L_0__?productId=3318610) that can be used in wall thicknesses over 1", but they're not going to go all the way to 2" thick.

[image: Old work metal box]

I *think* this is what you're talking about, but your question could use more details...

Answer (score 0):

When ever possible i use this old work box.

I find that the tabs are adjustable to around an inch or so. ( ***you will need to test for your application*** )  I usually run the screw in an out of the tab once ( *before i set it in the wall* ) to set the threads in the plastic, i find if i do not so this that sometimes the tabs twists in the wall and does not set right.   [image: oldwork box][image]